# Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'use' must be of type 'SVGProps', but here has type 'SVGProps'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, react-dom

I am coding in typescript and using awesome-typescript-loader. When I try to compile my code I get the following error numerous times:

"ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/searchkit/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:2790:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'switch' must be of type 'SVGProps', but here has type 'SVGProps'."

All my errors are with this SVGProps type. It's the same type as the one it wants so how should I fix this?

In index.d.ts these are the variables:
[Variable in index.d.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHdCU.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: I've got the same issue using stuff in @types/react and using searchkit.

Comment: @mmmveggies I actually fixed it, I'll post answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that @types/react is installed twice. In my case it is installed under node_modules/@types/react and node_modules/searchkit/node_modules/@types/react. What you need to do is go into node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts and remove everything pertaining to SVGProps. This will fix it.

Comment: How does this help? I mean, what is the logic behind it?